Java WEB application - Servlet con error 404
Estoy desarrollando un proyecto para clase en JAVA. Estoy usando Netbeans 23 y he integrado GlassFish 7.0.15 como servidor web.
En la raíz de la aplicación tengo el index.html:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="/Login" method="post">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
            <br>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <p style="color: red;">
                <% if (request.getParameter("error") != null) { %>
                    Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.
                <% } %>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

en el paquete controller me he creado un LoginServlet.java:
    package controller;
    
    import model.User;
    import model.UserDAO;
    
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    @WebServlet("/Login")
    public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private UserDAO userDAO;
    
        @Override
        public void init() throws ServletException {
            userDAO = new UserDAO(); // Inicializa el modelo
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
    
            User user = new User(username, password);
            boolean isValid = userDAO.validateUser(user);
    
            if (isValid) {
                response.sendRedirect("welcome.html"); // Redirige a una página de bienvenida
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("login.html?error=true"); // Redirige de vuelta al login con un mensaje de error
            }
        }
    }

y también he creado web.xml en WebPages>WEB-INF:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>controller.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>

Esta es la estructura del proyecto (necesito que sea MVC).

Al entrar a http://localhost:8080/RedSocial/ me carga el index.html, pero cuando envio el formulario me da error 404 not found.
¿Que puede estar pasando? Llevo un par de días siguiendo tutoriales y demás, pero no consigo solucionarlo.
¡Muchas gracias!

Te está dando 404, por que las rutas estan mal hechas en el html.
Deberías tener algo como:
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Login" method="post">

Esto es porque, lo que tienes ahora, es una ruta absoluta. Y dices que vaya directo a action="/Login", por eso termina diciendo que no lo ha encontrado.
El otro modo, es asi, pero depende de la clase y su lugar.
<form action="Login" method="post">

